# If I push a cloned repo, will it have everything that the cloned repo has?

Tags: git, github

I'm getting a bit confused with Git!

- I cloned a repo on GitHub **to a local drive**.
- I made some changes and committed to my local repo
- At this point, I couldn't figure out how to clone my local repo to a new GitHub repo, so I went to GitHub.com and created a new repo with their web interface
- I then did a `git-push MyNewRepoOnGitHub master`

Does `MyNewRepoOnGitHub` have everything that I originally cloned?  Can I send a **pull request** to the contributors of the project that I originally cloned?  Or... am I being completely thick and need to reread what I thought I knew about Git?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your new repository on github will only contain all commits reachable from `master` (you only pushed master). To push all refs (including tags), use `git push MyNewRepoOnGitHub --all`.

I don't use github myself, but a pull request should be possible. Commits don't change when cloned or pushed (but it could be possible that github requires you to 'fork' the project first). Pulling and merging from your both your cloned repositories will definitely work (with plain git)

Comment: Actually, if you want a complete mirror you need to follow the directions here: http://help.github.com/move-a-repo/  Pushing with `--all` only pushes your local references.

Comment: @Tekkub: yes, you could use `--mirror`, but this will create the exact same ref-structure on the remote, which is rarely wanted (not when pushing a local clone with associated worktree and configured remote)

Comment: Sure, but he did ask for "everything that I originally cloned"... sounds to me like he wants a mirror of the original repo as a base before he pushes up his commits.

Comment: @Tekkub: he cloned with worktree (and a remote), so `--all` is needed. `--mirror` would create one layer of indirection too many (namely creating `origin/*` refs on the remote).

Comment: that guide tells you to use `--bare` so that doesn't happen.

Comment: @Tekkub: I'm assuming here the OP did a full clone (including worktree). He didn't mention anything about a bare repository. Also he does not want to move a repository, he wants to know if it can still be pulled from. And mirroring the repository does not solve the problem, that it wasn't "forked" using github's webinterface …

Comment: @Tekkub let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2481/discussion-between-knittl-and-tekkub)

Answer (score 2):

I think you will have to explicitly "fork" the original repo to raise a pull request. Github currently doesn't know that your `MyNewRepoOnGitHub` is related to the original repo you cloned from. Forking establishes this relation and allows for pull requests to be raised to share commits.

You can:

1. Fork the original repo from which you cloned
2. Setup the forked repo as an additional remote repository (for the existing cloned repo on your machine)

   ```
      git remote add MyForkedRepo <url-to-your-forked-repo>
   ```
3. Push your changes to the forked repo

   ```
      git push MyForkedRepo master
   ```
4. Raise a pull request on Github

Without forking there are two ways, albeit very ancient looking compared to the pull request approach,

1. The original repo commiter/owner will have to add your `MyNewRepoOnGithub` as his remote and pull your changes and merge them and push them the original repo
2. You email the original repo owner a patch and he applies and commits to the repo on your behalf